# Azure-Pipelines Download a large number of secured files

Tags: azure-pipelines

Azure-Pipelines has a limit of 10Mb for each secure file you upload. Unfortunately I am working with a commercial 3rd party library which is more than 150Mb. So I zipped, split and upload my files (16 of them). Now when design my pipeline for each file I have to add a `Download Secured file` task and have to repeat this process for each release of the 3rd party commercial framework. Is it possible to automate this with a Powershelll script or another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Task Group, then use the task group directly in other pipelines.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer however it does not resolve my problem. I still have to update the task group on every release of the 3rd party library which may be often and I have to upload manually a large number of files. I am looking for a way to script this with Powershell if possible.

Comment: Do you mean you use different secure files every time in pipelines? If it is, I don't think you can simply implement that by powershell to split and upload... . However the `Download Secured file` task will download the secure file to a temp folder `$(Agent.TempDirectory)`. So you can try copying the secure file directly to that temp folder to check if that works.